# Cannot display variable html side

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my project I want to display a variable to html side, but I get this message.

My code behind

```
   ShipperResposite _shiperResposite = new ShipperResposite();

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return Price; }
        set
        {
            Price=_shiperResposite.GetPriceFromID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            Price = value;
        }
    }
```

My html side

```
 <div class="prod_price_big"><span class="reduce">350$</span><%=Price %><span class="price"> </span></div>
```

I want price to display in html side.

Comment: How are you rendering the content to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Use `asp:Label`

html

```
<div class="prod_price_big">
   <span class="reduce">350$</span>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PriceLabel" CssClass="price"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

code-behind

```
PriceLabel.Text = this.Price.ToString();
```

Comment: Even if ı delete <%=Price %> part

this code block give me erore mesage 

public decimal Price
    {
        get { return Price; }
        set
        {
            Price=_shiperResposite.GetPriceFromID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            Price = value;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
 public decimal Price
    {
        get { return Price; }
        set
        {
            Price=_shiperResposite.GetPriceFromID(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            Price = value;
        }
    }
```

That block of code is a pretty big problem that will result in a stack overflow.

`Price` is the name of your property.  The very first thing that occurs inside the set method is that you set the property to some value, which causes the set method to execute again and again and again... until the app completely craters with a highly puzzling error message.

This really should be:

```
 private decimal _price = 0.00M;

 public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
        _price = value;
        }
    }
```

Note that I removed the `Price = shiperResposite...;` part.  I'm not sure what you were trying to do by setting price to both the set value AND from the GetPriceFromID piece.
Either way, setting a property value *within the setter* using a querystring call is a total fail and needs to be rethought.